# Objectify - How to use new Firestore in Datastore mode filters !=, IN, NOT_IN

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

In the objectify [docs](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries#executing-queries) it shows these operators:

```
// Operators are >, >=, <, <=, in, !=, <>, =, ==
List<Car> cars = ofy().load().type(Car.class).filter("year >", 1999).list();
List<Car> cars = ofy().load().type(Car.class).filter("year >=", 1999).list();
List<Car> cars = ofy().load().type(Car.class).filter("year !=", 1999).list();
List<Car> cars = ofy().load().type(Car.class).filter("year in", yearList).list();
// Note that Objectify 6+ does not provide != or IN (this is not yet supported by the underlying Cloud SDK)
```

Two questions:

1. I think the comment about `!=` or `IN` might be outdated because the google [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#not-equal) show these as supported but only in Firestore in Datastore mode (which at this point, every/most database should be that since the original Datastore is being auto-migrated to Firestore). So I assume the `!=` and `IN` filters should just work if we use them in objectify?
2. What is the way to write a NOT_IN filter? It is also something [new](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#not_in) in Firestore in Datastore mode. Is this how you would write it: `.filter("year not_in", yearList)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [code](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/blob/ec41e6193792b77088cc00daf94c7e3f75daaf3c/src/main/java/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/QueryImpl.java#L189) & [release notes](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/ReleaseNotes), you can use !in for NOT_IN.